# Passing encoder output into fully connected layer

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I have an LSTM based encoder with the final hidden state dimensions as `[2, 1, 1024]`. Here, 2 is the number of layers, 1 is batch size and 1024 is hidden size. I am trying to pass the encoded form into a fully connected layer to train a classifier.

The problem is that the `torch.nn.Linear` takes input in the form `(N,∗,Hin)` where N is the batch size, and Hin is the hidden size. How do I reshape the output of the encoder given that there is no mention of the number of layers in the input of `torch.nn.Linear`?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example take the last step output of your RNN and feed it into the fully connected network. This would be a matter of selected the last element of your tensor. In this case, the first dense layer would have a total of `hidden_size` neurons. In this scenario, the dense layer's input would have a shape of `(1, out_features)` since `batch_size=1`. Something like:

```
>>> fc = nn.Linear(1024, 512) # for demonstration purposes
>>> x, _ = lstm(x)

>>> fc(x[-1:, 0]).shape
(1, 1024)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also feed the whole tensor. As you described it [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) works with multi-dimensional tensors. In this case we are inferring on the whole output of the RNN, not just its last step output:

```
>>> fc = nn.Linear(1024, 512) # for demonstration purposes
>>> x, _ = lstm(x)

>>> fc(x).shape
(2, 1, 512)
```

Be aware though, the second dimension (here of size `1`) will remain your batch axis. If you don't want it this way and prefer having it on `axis=0`, you can init your [`nn.LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) with the `batch_first=True` option. You could also permute `axis=0` and `axis=1`...

To give an answer to your question, there is no need to give the number of layers to `nn.Linear`, it will automatically flatten all dimensions except the last (feature dimension), and reshape back the output to the corresponding shape.